# Where is tortoisesvn-settings-network-enableProxyServer stored?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to copy all tortoisesvn network  settings from one machine to another. Where are these stored?

I did this,

Save:

`reg save HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tortoise.hive`

Restore:

`reg restore HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tortoise.hive`

but it can not copy the `enable proxy server`  value correctly ,it always not checked.

so how can I get the correctly `enable proxy server` value, or what is the registry value of the `enable proxy server`?

thanks!

-----------------edit--------------------------

I still can not found the `enable proxy server` registry. I read the docs, set the `http-proxy` is ok, but there is no place to set `enable proxy server` that what I want to know !

like this :

[image]

Comment: Read the docs, please: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-network & http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers

Comment: after read the tortoisesvn source code , I understood how the `enable-proxy-server` works.

`
    if (m_serveraddress.IsEmpty())
    {
        m_isEnabled = FALSE;
        EnableGroup(FALSE);
       }
`
It will look `CRegString(L"Software\\Tigris.org\\Subversion\\Servers\\global\\http-proxy-host", L"")` registry value first, then update`enable proxy server` checkbox's state . so ,  just need to set the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Servers\global\http-proxy-host` .

Comment: the final reg file: 

REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Servers\global]
"http-proxy-host"="proxy.domain.com"
"http-proxy-port"="9070"